# How to hide the controls in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have added some controls and tab control in my window. now i want to hide the controls when ever user presses tabItem2, like that for each tabItem i need some controls should be displayed and some should be hide how to proceed this type of functionality?

Comment: You could bind the controls' visibility to the selected item of the tab control.  Use an `IValueConverter` to get the appropriate `Visiblility` value.

Answer (score 2):

just declare the controls in your TabControl

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <Button x:Name="Button1"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <Button/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Or you can hide the controls you want by handling the SelectionChanged event of the TabControl.

```
void OnTabControlSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: Please add a comment why -1.

Comment: -1. Do not manipulate uielements in code. this is not winforms. that approach is appalling in WPF because it produces tight coupling between XAML defined elements and (completely unnecessary) C# code.

Comment: I dont know the reason why yug wants to hide some controls. But because he writes that the visibility of these controls is depending of the activated tab, it seems to me, that this could be a UI thing. And you can handle UI things in code behind. In my opinion it is not the right way to not write code that manipulate the ui elements just because it is WPF or XAML or MVVM...

Answer (score 0):

For Clarification: do you mean that for each tabitem you press, you would like a different set of tabitems to be visible? If so, I'd suggest wrapping that functionality up in a UserControl, and providing the "set" logic as part of the codebehind for that control.